# Activerecord associations and migrations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a model Ride. A ride has one driver and one user
Im trying to implement a Rating for the the rides
Each Rating must belong to a ride.
Id like to have the associations and models such that I can call
Driver.ratings and it gives me all ratings for that driver(through the rides table)
and call User.ratings gives me a list of all ratings for that user(through the rides table)

```
class Ride < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :driver, optional: true
  belongs_to :user, optional: true
end


class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :rides
end


class Driver < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :rides
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use [has_many through](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) associations

In your Drive and User model, you can add following associations

```
class Driver < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :rides
  has_many :ratings, through: :rides
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :rides
  has_many :ratings, through: :rides
end
```

Comment: Would any new migrations be necessary? or would adding those associations be enough

Comment: As per your above model structure, No migration should be needed. Just add the associations